# my-voice-analysis myspsolution module not found error

Tags: python-3.x, voice-recognition

we are using python library my-voice-analysis but getting myspsolution import error please tell what is the [solution](https://pypi.org/project/my-voice-analysis/)

```
import myspsolution as mysp

p="Audio" # Audio File title
c=r"speech.wav"
mysp.myspgend(p,c)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\ADITYA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\sp.py", line 1, in <module>
    import myspsolution as mysp
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myspsolution'
```

Answer (score 3):

i know its a bit late and you probs dont need it anymore but
replace

`import myspsolution as mysp`

with

`mysp=__import__("my-voice-analysis")`